# reconstruct binary search tree from a flatten list in Java?

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, preorder

I have this code for reconstructing a binary search tree from a flattened list of pre-order`traversal elements.

I see this code working but unable to understand how.  Here is the code:

```
public static Node reconstructfromflattenBST(List<Integer> list){
        if (list.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }
        int data = list.remove(0);
        Node root = new Node(data);
        root.left=reconstructfromflattenBST(list);
        root.right=reconstructfromflattenBST(list);

        return root;



    }
```

From my understanding of this method, there will be no right tree created. since when the control reaches `root.right`, the `list` is empty. But this method apparently works.

I gave a pre-order input of [5 3 1 4 8 6 9]. After the tree is constructed, I did a pre-order traversal of the constructed tree and it gives the same order of elements as the input list.

EDIT:
here is my Flattening subroutine:

```
public static List<Integer> flattenBinaryTree(Node root, List<Integer> list){

        if (list==null){
            list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
        if (root==null){
            return list;
        }
        list.add(root.data);
        List<Integer> list1 = flattenBinaryTree(root.left,list);
        return flattenBinaryTree(root.right, list1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. If on flattening the tree null Nodes were written out too, maybe as null Integer, then:

```
    Integer data = list.remove(0);
    if (data == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Node root = new Node(data.intValue());
```

would reconstruct the exact same tree.
That is: flattening adds the stopping null leafs.

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
flatten(list, tree);

void flatten(List<Integer> list, Node tree) {
    if (tree == null) {
        list.add(null);
        return;
    }
    list.add(tree.data);
    flatten(tree.left);
    flatten(tree.right);
}
```

Or with an ordered tree:

```
public static Node reconstructfromflattenBST(List<Integer> list){
    reconstruct(list, Integer.MAX_VALUE, true);
}

public static Node reconstruct(List<Integer> list, int priorData, boolean left){
    if (list.isEmpty()){
        return null;
    }
    int data = list.remove(0);
    if ((data <= priorData) != left) {
        return null;
    }
    Node root = new Node(data);
    root.left=reconstruct(list, data, true);
    root.right=reconstruct(list, data, false);

    return root;
}
```

Comment: I think the `right subtree` is never constructed, because the list is emptied before `it reaches that line of code where `root.right` is assigned

Comment: as you can see above my code, I do not do a `data==null` check, how does that work?

Comment: I have included my flattening subroutine, it works with that.

Comment: You get a tree with nodes where only the left branch is filled.

Comment: exactly..but when I do a pre-order traversal, it prints the input list correctly, how is that?

Comment: The order of values is maintained, it only is a tree that in fact is a diagonal list.

Comment: so the tree is different after I flatten? is it? before flattening it is branched with left and right subtrees but after flattening and reconstructing, I get only left branch filled, which means I am not reconstructing the same tree

Comment: Another question on same note? I was under the impression that a given pre-order traversal can result in only one BST and not more?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45223/discussion-between-user1988876-and-joop-eggen)

Comment: a pre-order traversal array will give a unique binary search tree. please this post of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146851/binary-search-tree-persistence-and-retrival-of-it-by-pre-order-reconstruction-in

Comment: I got convinced too, but consider still the reconstruction of `5(5(3,4),-)` and `5(-,5(6,7))` or even `553567` - at least for unit tests. In 5534 and 5567 one does not know whether the second 5 is for left or right. It will come out right though maybe `5(5,6(-,7))`. **And thanks for the thought impulse.**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45401/discussion-between-user1988876-and-joop-eggen)

Comment: I guess you are correct when it comes to duplicates. but when I flatten a binary search tree and if it has duplicates, I will consider keeping in left tree, so when I read back from the list, I will construct the tree accordingly..make sense?

Comment: can you see my post on chat?

Answer (score 1):

> From my understanding of this method, there will be no right tree created. since when the control reaches `root.right`, the `list` is empty.

That's right.

> But this method apparently works.
>
> I gave a pre-order input of [5 3 1 4 8 6 9]. After the tree is constructed, I did a pre-order traversal of the constructed tree and it gives the same order of elements as the input list.

That observation doesn't contradict that the right subtrees are always empty.

A better unit test would construct a tree, flatten it, reconstruct it, and compare that the reconstructed tree has the same shape as the original one. Such a test would fail. In fact, it is impossible to faithfully reconstruct a tree from a preorder list of nodes, because different trees have the same preorder list. For instance, both

```
1              1
 \            / \
  2          2   3
   \
    3
```

have the preorder list 1 2 3.

Comment: The one on left is not a BST. The idea is here tree structure persistence into array and reconstructing back the same tree. pre-order array is best since it is possible to reconstruct BST from it and not from anything else..

Comment: Right, if the numbers are distinct, a BST is identified by its preorder list, but the tree you reconstruct isn't a BST.

Comment: I guess you are right. The above re-construction does not give back a valid BST.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is writing out the preorder values of the tree does not guarantee that the tree was originally a BST, thus the output of the initial function should be a stick going down the left side with 5 as the root.

```
      5
     3
    1
   4
  8
 6
9
```

This tree has a preorder traversal of [5, 3, 1, 4, 8, 6, 9], it is however not a BST, and therefore not the correct representation of the tree. Joop Eggen appears the correct version(s)